# Glassfish Embedded JMS Broker Masterbroker settings

Tags: jms, glassfish-3

In a cluster of 3 instances all of the instances complain that they cannot work with the other because the master broker of the other is different then their own master broker.

I tried to convince the embedded conventional broker's to believe me that the first instance has to be the master of the 3. But after restarting the brokers they ignore the changes and do the same as before.

```
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/nodes/localhost-domain3/qisi1/imq/instances/QISqisi1/props/config.properties
```

content:

```
imq.cluster.masterbroker=172.1.1.1\:27681
```

From the log.txt:

```
[06/Nov/2014:15:31:26 MEZ] ERROR [B3097]: Configuration mismatch: Aborting connection with broker [ mq://172.20.2.219:27681/?instName=TESTtesti1&brokerSessionUID=780047997950335488 ] because master broker does not match. This broker has master broker mq://172.20.2.220:27681/, broker [ mq://172.20.2.219:27681/?instName=TESTtesti1&brokerSessionUID=780047997950335488 ] has master broker mq://172.20.2.219:27681/
```

This issue is only happening on our LIVE System Glassfish Version 3.1.2

What do I do wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cluster instances was located on a "CONFIG" node. After replaceing it with a local SSH node the instances where able to determine a master broker and started doing their work.